# Transfer movie using itunes

Tags: itunes, windows

I am trying to follow the simple instructions given at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAI2V5q-4Bs to transfer a movie from my laptop to my ipad.  However, when I run itunes in windows with the ipad plugged in I don't see the left hand pane at all. How can I get to the screen they have at 31 seconds into that video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video is for iTunes 10 or before, I assume you are using iTunes 11 now. After plugging in your iPad click on the "Devices" button at top right (next to "iTunes Store") and then on Apps (about in the middle) to get to the same screen again.

Comment: Thanks! In fact the "ipad" button in the top right next to "itunes store" just disappeared when I clicked on it before but after leaving it for a while it now works.